# System boots into a console when installing with the alternate CD

Tags: installation

I just installed 12.04 Alternate for the first time to give it a try using a USB stick burned with UnetBootIn.

It installed without a problem. But it booted into a `tty1` console without booting into a GUI.

After logging into the `tty1` console, I typed `unity`. It appeared that the system doesn't have unity desktop. How can it be solved? My installation didn't show any error.

Something worth mentioning:

1. During installation, I had to choose an option saying 'customize the system to your needs' something like that I don't remember correctly with options 'SSH server','Mail Server', 'Ubuntu Desktop',.....,'Manual selection of packages' etc. I chose 'Ubuntu Desktop'. I haven't encountered something like this in 11.04.
2. To do an installation of Alternate iso using UnetBootIn, i used '12.04_Hdmedia' option of that software and had to change file extension of .ude to .udeb in /pool/main/l/linux that i found in [Alternate ubuntu cdrom detect](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unetbootin/+bug/297409)  to go around with the cdrom detection problem.
3. I have a 945G intel graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Login then type these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

or

if you prefer Xubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

or

if you prefer Kubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: why ubuntu desktop was not installed ? can anybody tell me that.

Comment: I used to have a problem with the installer when I reached the cdrom to install the base system, it showed me an error and I cannot continue to install the "base system" So I skied the installation of the base system and I was faced with a tty1. This happened when I used a cheap USB. After changing the USB and downloading another alternate CD, the installation worked. Am not sure about yours.